# syntax error in python 2.7.9 IDLE

Tags: linux, python-2.7, debugging, raspberry-pi, text-editor

I am currently writing a script that allows me to control a robotic arm from a wii remote. I've written the script in Python 2 IDLE and when I press F5 to run the script an error message pops up:

```
         There's an error in your program:
         invalid syntax
```

After pressing 'OK' to exit the message and return to the script at fault, the number '7' in 'Python 2.7.9' is highlighted in red on line 1 of the script:

```
         Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar 8 2015, 00:52:26)
         [GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
```

I haven't a clue how to fix such an error seeing as how I didn't even create it. I cant run the script via Linux's terminal due to the same error message being given. Any  help will be gratefully received so if anyone has any clue it'll be helpful.

And the reason I am not using Python 3 IDLE is be because the script I am referring from would need a lot of alterations that I don't fully know how to make yet.

Comment: Try posting the code you've created.

Comment: Ive just tried to post the whole code but its too long by 1145 characters. If you give me your email I'll be happy to pass it over

Comment: While I appreciate it, that defeats the purpose of stack exchange.  Try this instead.  Copy the script into it's own python file; something like myrobot.py and execute it in commandline.  If there is a syntax problem the stack trace will print out.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, since posting the post I have fixed the version error, it was a case of scripting it in a completely empty python shell without executing each line when pressing enter. However, since then I've run into another problem. When I run the script via Linux's terminal or F5 a blank screen is returned, no actions that connect the wii remote nor the Maplin's robotic arm.

Comment: I would advise you don't execute scripts in idle. Running them from commandline will serve you better in the long run.  Also I highly recommend a good IDE/debugger.  This will help you step through the lines of code in your script.

Comment: I am now attempting to run the script via the commandline yet still a blank linefeed is returned, I've debugged my script and there are no syntax errors yet I still cant connect the robotic arm and wii remote to the pi. It would seem that that the pi doesn't recognise the robotic arm even though they are connected via usb. I am also using a third-party wii remote which may also be part of the problem. Any idea's?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can only speculate.  It sounds like you're taking on a couple issues at once.  I would start to isolate.  Focus on one issue at a time.  The blank linefeed should be easy enough to determine.  Put a print statement before and after where you suspect it might be occurring. Then move them closer to each other until you don't see the blank line between the print statements.